# JavaScript: removing EventListener inside the function calling that EventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a decimal button for an in-browser calculator using vanilla JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. The problem that I am having is trying to turn off the decimal button after using it incase of nonsense numbers (ie 3.1.4.0), however my code isn't as intended:

```
//global constants
const calcchoices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".allbtns"));
const decimalbtn = document.querySelector("#decimal");

function buttonpressing(e){

    document.getElementById("display").value += e.target.value //updates the display with what you pressed

    //if decimal is pressed, make sure you cant press it again
    if(e.target.id === "decimal"){
        //turn off the decimal event listener only
        decimalbtn.removeEventListener("click", buttonpressing);
    }
}
calcchoices.forEach(choice => choice.addEventListener("click", buttonpressing))
```

Here is the HTML for this (there were more "number" buttons such as 0 but I deleted them for this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--This is the html file for the calculator-->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calculator" class="allbtns">
        <input type="text" name="display" id="display" style="grid-area: display" disabled>
        <!--Numbers-->
        <button id="0" value="0" class="number" style="grid-area:zero">0</button>
        <button id="decimal" class ="number" style="grid-area:decimal" value=".">.</button>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- JS source-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
</html>
```

I am unsure why I can remove that EventListener for the decimalbtn? I suspect it is part of calling the forEach method inside of calcchoices.

Comment: You added the click handler to the `<div id="calculator" class="allbtns">` ... try `const calcchoices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".allbtns .number"));` instead

Answer (score 3):

You added the click handler to the `<div id="calculator" class="allbtns">` ... try `const calcchoices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".allbtns .number"));` instead

You can then use `this` instead of `e.target` as well

```js
const calcchoices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".allbtns .number"));
const decimalbtn = document.querySelector("#decimal");

function buttonpressing(e) {
  document.getElementById("display").value += this.value;
  if (this.id === "decimal") {
    this.removeEventListener("click", buttonpressing);
  }
}
calcchoices.forEach(choice => choice.addEventListener("click", buttonpressing))
```

```html
<div id="calculator" class="allbtns">
  <input type="text" name="display" id="display" style="grid-area: display" disabled>
  <!--Numbers-->
  <button id="d0" value="0" class="number" style="grid-area:zero">0</button>
  <button id="decimal" class="number" style="grid-area:decimal" value=".">.</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! 
But why? Why is choosing the general "allbtns" class prohibiting me from removing the EventListener?

Comment: you add ONE event listener to ONE element, the div - there are no event listeners on the inputs inside it

Comment: Ok that clears it up for me. I was under the impression that the EventListener "bubbled down" to its child nodes.